# What does it mean "Unrecognized hbm2ddl_auto value : update "

Tags: hibernate, maven, spring-boot, jpa, jakarta-ee

```
 JPA cannot create table automatically with following error message:
```

(Please note , in particular, message extracted from below: “2019-09-18 06:01:52.776  WARN 12248 --- [main] o.h.b.i.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl        : Unrecognized hbm2ddl_auto value : update  .  Supported values include create, create-drop, update, and validate.  Ignoring”。)

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v1.5.21.RELEASE)

2019-09-18 06:01:37.455  INFO 12248 --- [           main] c.s.mirrorworld.mirrorworldApplication   : Starting mirrorworldApplication on LAPTOP-FAS0SHLM with PID 12248 (C:\Users\yueho\eclipse-workspace\mirrorworld\target\classes started by yueho in C:\Users\yueho\eclipse-workspace\mirrorworld)
2019-09-18 06:01:37.466  INFO 12248 --- [           main] c.s.mirrorworld.mirrorworldApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-09-18 06:01:37.766  INFO 12248 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2f217633: startup date [Wed Sep 18 06:01:37 CST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-09-18 06:01:43.613  INFO 12248 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-09-18 06:01:43.662  INFO 12248 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-09-18 06:01:43.955  INFO 12248 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2019-09-18 06:01:43.959  INFO 12248 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-09-18 06:01:43.962  INFO 12248 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2019-09-18 06:01:44.282  INFO 12248 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2019-09-18 06:01:51.899  INFO 12248 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

***2019-09-18 06:01:52.776  WARN 12248 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl        : Unrecognized hbm2ddl_auto value : update  .  Supported values include create, create-drop, update, and validate.  Ignoring***
    2019-09-18 06:01:53.639  INFO 12248 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2019-09-18 06:01:58.151  INFO 12248 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
    2019-09-18 06:01:58.180  INFO 12248 --- [           main] c.s.mirrorworld.mirrorworldApplication   : Started mirrorworldApplication in 21.641 seconds (JVM running for 23.004)
    2019-09-18 06:02:20.999  INFO 12248 --- [WT-EventQueue-0] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
    Hibernate: select unit_quant0_.id as id1_18_, unit_quant0_.formula as formula2_18_, unit_quant0_.name as name3_18_, unit_quant0_.symbol as symbol4_18_, unit_quant0_.unit_quantity_type as unit_qua5_18_ from unit_quantity unit_quant0_ where unit_quant0_.id=?
    2019-09-18 06:02:21.607  WARN 12248 --- [WT-EventQueue-0] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
    2019-09-18 06:02:21.607 ERROR 12248 --- [WT-EventQueue-0] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table 'mirrorworld.unit_quantity' doesn't exist
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:492)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:375)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.getResultList(Unknown Source)
        at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p2_base_bean.Thing_Persistence_Service.Simply_get_thing_list(Thing_Persistence_Service.java:498)
        at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p2_base_bean.Thing_Persistence_Service.Get_thing_list_simpler_query_string(Thing_Persistence_Service.java:461)
        at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p3_application_bean.Thing.Thing_Aspect.Verify_component_value_duplication_checking(Thing_Aspect.java:290)
        at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p3_application_bean.Thing.Thing_Aspect.Verify_component_value(Thing_Aspect.java:157)
        at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p3_application_bean.Thing.Thing_Aspect.Verify_component_values(Thing_Aspect.java:116)
        at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p3_application_bean.Thing.Thing_Aspect.Verify_component_values_before_saving(Thing_Aspect.java:74)
        at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p2_base_bean.Thing_List_Service.Save_thing_list(Thing_List_Service.java:470)
        at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p2_base_bean.Thing_List_Service.Manage_user_intention(Thing_List_Service.java:68)
        at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p2_base_bean.Thing_Editor_Dispatcher.Manage_user_intention(Thing_Editor_Dispatcher.java:28)
        at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p4_view.Listener_Thing_List_Editor_View_Button.actionPerformed(Listener_Thing_List_Editor_View_Button.java:38)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2117)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326)
        at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)
        ... 52 more
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'mirrorworld.unit_quantity' doesn't exist
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3978)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3914)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2495)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1903)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2011)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
        ... 68 more
    Hibernate: select unit_quant0_.id as id1_18_, unit_quant0_.formula as formula2_18_, unit_quant0_.name as name3_18_, unit_quant0_.symbol as symbol4_18_, unit_quant0_.unit_quantity_type as unit_qua5_18_ from unit_quantity unit_quant0_ where unit_quant0_.id=?
    2019-09-18 06:02:22.120  WARN 12248 --- [WT-EventQueue-0] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
    2019-09-18 06:02:22.121 ERROR 12248 --- [WT-EventQueue-0] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table 'mirrorworld.unit_quantity' doesn't exist
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:492)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:375)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.getResultList(Unknown Source)
        at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p2_base_bean.Thing_Persistence_Service.Simply_get_thing_list(Thing_Persistence_Service.java:498)
        at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p2_base_bean.Thing_Persistence_Service.Get_thing_list_simpler_query_string(Thing_Persistence_Service.java:461)
        at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p3_application_bean.Thing.Thing_Aspect.Verify_component_value_duplication_checking(Thing_Aspect.java:290)
        at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p3_application_bean.Thing.Thing_Aspect.Verify_component_value(Thing_Aspect.java:157)
        at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p3_application_bean.Thing.Thing_Aspect.Verify_component_values(Thing_Aspect.java:116)
        at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p3_application_bean.Thing.Thing_Aspect.Verify_component_values_before_saving(Thing_Aspect.java:74)
        at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p2_base_bean.Thing_List_Service.Save_thing_list(Thing_List_Service.java:470)
        at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p2_base_bean.Thing_List_Service.Manage_user_intention(Thing_List_Service.java:68)
        at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p2_base_bean.Thing_Editor_Dispatcher.Manage_user_intention(Thing_Editor_Dispatcher.java:28)
        at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p4_view.Listener_Thing_List_Editor_View_Button.actionPerformed(Listener_Thing_List_Editor_View_Button.java:38)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2117)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326)
        at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)
        ... 52 more
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'mirrorworld.unit_quantity' doesn't exist
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3978)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3914)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2495)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1903)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2011)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
        ... 68 more
    2019-09-18 06:02:23.818  INFO 12248 --- [       Thread-4] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2f217633: startup date [Wed Sep 18 06:01:37 CST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
    2019-09-18 06:02:23.821  INFO 12248 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
    2019-09-18 06:02:23.849  INFO 12248 --- [       Thread-4] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

**1.APPLICATION PROPERTIES**
   ============================

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mirrorworld
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=mirror
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.max-idle=10
spring.datasource.max-wait=10000
spring.datasource.min-idle=5
spring.datasource.initial-size=5
server.port=8011
server.session.timeout=10
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.format_sql=false
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true  
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update  
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy  
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

**2.SPRINGBOOTAPPLICATION**
   ================

```
@EntityScan
(   basePackages = 
{
    "com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p3_application_bean.Unit"
}
)
@EnableJpaRepositories
(
    basePackages = 
{
    "com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p3_application_bean.Unit"
}
)

@SpringBootApplication
public class mirrorworldApplication
{
......
}

**3.ENTITY**
============

@Entity
public class Unit_Quantity extends Thing 
{
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="assigned", strategy="assigned")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="assigned")
    @Column(nullable=false,length=100)
    private String Id;  
    @Column(nullable=false,length=150)
    private String Name;
    @Column(nullable=false,length=20)
    private String Unit_Quantity_Type;
    @Column(nullable=false,length=20)
    private String Symbol;
    @Column(nullable=true,length=100)
    private String Formula; 
    ......
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried "create" instead of "update", just to check if table is created with create

Comment: There are blanks after the word "update" in application.properties, and Hibernate seems to be picking them up, as apparent from the error message. Try removing them.

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem solved by removing the space, sorry for such a stupid error.